# Inserting values from mysql_fetch_assoc into form input

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

I have som problem writing back to table.
I connect to table as wanted and get the information output correctly. The input correctedby, and the checkboxes is saving as i want.
 but i dont know how  to write the mysql_fetch_assoc back to table
I have this kode;

```
    <?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['mypassword']="myusername";
echo "Logged in as:<br>"  .$_SESSION['myusername'];

include "header.inc.php";
   include "funksjoner.inc.php";
//in this file the connetion to server

   $connection= kobleTil(); //trenger ikke oppgi databasenavn

//Steg 2:  SQL-query
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM oppgave  WHERE modulid=1 AND resultat is NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";


$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection); 
echo "<hr>";
while ($nextrow= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "answer: " . $nextrow['answer'];
    echo "<br>Modulid: " . $nextrow['modulid'];
        echo "<br>student: " . $nextrow['studentid'];
        echo "<br>";
}

echo '<form name="input" action="tilretting.php" method="get">';
echo'<input type="text" name="correctedby" value="'.$_SESSION['myusername'].'">';
echo 'Not approved<input type="checkbox" name="resultat" value="0">';
echo 'Approved<input type="checkbox" name="resultat" value="1">';
echo '<input type="text" name="studentid" value="dont know how to write correct here">';
echo '<input class="levermodulknapp" type="submit" name="lever1" value="Lever modul 1">';
echo  "</form>";
echo "<hr>";
?>
```

how can I get the form to get the value from mysql_fetch_assoc into the form?
Is the mysql_fetch_assoc the right thing to use?
Very gratefull for any tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection); 
echo "<hr>";
while ($nextrow= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "answer: " . $nextrow['answer'];
    echo "<br>Modulid: " . $nextrow['modulid'];
        echo "<br>student: " . $nextrow['studentid'];
        echo "<br>";

echo '<form name="input" action="tilretting.php" method="get">';
    echo'<input type="text" name="correctedby" value="'.$_SESSION['myusername'].'">';
    echo 'Not approved<input type="checkbox" name="resultat" value="0">';
    echo 'Approved<input type="checkbox" name="resultat" value="1">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="studentid" value="'.$nextrow['columnName'].'">';
    echo '<input class="levermodulknapp" type="submit" name="lever1" value="Lever modul 1">';
    echo  "</form>";
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

or

```
$data = null;
$result = mysql_query($sql, $connection); 
echo "<hr>";
while ($nextrow= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "answer: " . $nextrow['answer'];
    echo "<br>Modulid: " . $nextrow['modulid'];
        echo "<br>student: " . $nextrow['studentid'];
        echo "<br>";
     $data = $nextrow['colunmName'];
}


echo '<form name="input" action="tilretting.php" method="get">';
    echo'<input type="text" name="correctedby" value="'.$_SESSION['myusername'].'">';
    echo 'Not approved<input type="checkbox" name="resultat" value="0">';
    echo 'Approved<input type="checkbox" name="resultat" value="1">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="studentid" value="'.$data.'">';
    echo '<input class="levermodulknapp" type="submit" name="lever1" value="Lever modul 1">';
    echo  "</form>";
    echo "<hr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you so mutcg, god the first one to work right away, but how do i call the post values form the form action? one the corrected by i used the: $correctedby= $_POST['correctedby'];

Comment: so you have to change form method to post.  <form name="input" action="tilretting.php" method="post">

Comment: this i did, but it seems like it makes a new roe with values in the table. otherwise it almost work.

Comment: should i use this id in the table for insert the values not as duplikate?

Comment: so there is not enough information about your project. so i didnt understand that what do you want to do. i will help you if you insert more information about what do you want to do

Comment: now the values insert perfectly, but as a new row. I have in the table a id who is primary with auto_increment.

Comment: i try to use the update instead of insert, but then nothing is written to table

Comment: so you have to debug it. before inserting query, echo the values of the posted variables. and see if they are true or not null. if every thing ok, be sure that insert query running well

Comment: should i use update for this action? the values is written still in a new row. thought if i fetch the id who was primary and unique that it hade to add the inserted information